# How to change the '$' reference dynamically by code spliting with webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack

My  website needs to apply to the PC and mobile, but I would not like to use jQuery on mobile, instead I would like to use Zepto.  So the ideal solution is changing the '$' reference dynamically , the '$' will refer to Zepto when it runs on mobile and refer to jQuery on PC.

But  I could not control the Webpack resolving module order, there are  several plugins depending on '$' symbol , like `$.fn.xxx = ...`  the plugins always runs before the module in which  I use Webpack code spliting  .

the code spliting module like :

```
var $

if(isMobile) {
    require(['libs/zepto'],function (Zepto) {
    $ = Zepto
})
} else {
   require(['libs/jquery.min'],function (jQuery) {
   $ = jQuery 
})
}

export {$};
```

Comment: for jQuery use `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: @IvanKaraman  It  has  nothing to  do with conflict .Because when it  comes to running on PC ,there is only jQuery $ variable